# jQuery - Error: unsupported pseudo: visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

On the internet I see loads of examples using the `:visbile` pseudo selector (to filter  `display:none;`).

But when I try to use it jQuery gives an error:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported
>   pseudo: visible - jquery.min.js:2

---

This is what I did:

```
function initSimpleTinyMCE(selector) {
    console.log(selector+':visible');    // .simple-tinymce:visible
    tinymce.init({
        selector: selector+':visible',
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jQuery TinyMCE, you can use it like this:

```js
function initSimpleTinyMCE(selector) {
    $(selector+':visible').tinymce({
     // Options
    });
}

initSimpleTinyMCE('.simple-tinymce');
```

```css
.hidden {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinymce/4.5.6/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinymce/4.5.6/jquery.tinymce.min.js"></script>

<textarea class="simple-tinymce"></textarea>

<textarea class="simple-tinymce hidden"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tiny-MCE only supports css selectors.  The [`:visible`](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) pseudo-selector is specific to jQuery and as such can't be used this way.  Assuming you are using jQuery in your project, something like this would work:

```
funciton initSimpleTinyMCE(selector)
{
    var element = jQuery(selector+":visible").first(); //Just in case the selector matches multiple elements.
    tinymce.init({
        target: element[0]
    });
}
```

You may also want to implement a check to make sure the selector matches something in the dom before attempting to initialize Tiny-MCE.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way `function initSimpleTinyMCE(selector) { console.log($(selector+':visible'));tinymce.init({selector: $(selector+':visible'),});}`